# is there any possible to give information like 404 page error for javascript disabled

Tags: javascript, jquery

Hi all is there any possible to make a java script disabled message like `404 page not found` for java script disabled browsers by users.

Comment: The [`<noscript>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/noscript) tag may be of use to you.

Comment: You can either use the <noscript> tags or show a 'no javascript' message by default and strip it back out of the DOM with javascript, so that people with javascript don't see it.

Comment: Refer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3262479/how-to-inform-if-javascript-is-disabled-in-the-browser

Comment: @DarrenCrabb Those with JS enabled wouldn't see anything wrapped in `<noscript>`—there's no need to strip it out.

Comment: @AndréDion He's thinking of text outside of a `<noscript>` tag... But I don't like that solution, the message may flicker onscreen before JavaScript gets a chance to remove it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you mean that you literally want the web server to send back status code 404, exactly as though the resource had not been found, for a page requiring JavaScript, then you can't *reasonably* do that, no. The server doesn't know whether the browser supports JavaScript as of when it's processing the request.

You can include a message between `<noscript>...</noscript>` tags that will be shown by browsers with JavaScript disabled, but that's not a 404.

You may also be able to do this:

```
<noscript>
<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0; url=http://example.com/404.html">
</noscript>
```

...which would redirect non-JavaScript users to another page, which can be a 404. This is because the [`noscript` element](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/scripting-1.html#the-noscript-element) is allowed to contain meta information.

Answer (score 1):

Something like this?

```
<noscript>
    <div class="js-error">Javascript disabled.</div>
</noscript>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<noscript>JavaScript is disabled.</noscript>
```

---

Another strategy (one that [Modernizr](http://modernizr.com/) uses) is to add a `no-js` class to your `<html>` tag (`<html class="no-js">`) and then have some JS remove/replace that class on page load so that you may prefix selector statements in your stylesheet with a `.no-js` selector for custom display options:

```
.js .warning { display: none; } /* assumes .no-js is replaced with .js for those with JS enabled */

<html class="no-js">
   ...
   <div class="warning">JavaScript is disabled.</div>
   ...
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could "fake" it by including the html-code for something that looks like a 404 page inside a  section.

Answer (score 0):

```
<script>
//the script
</script>

<noscript>
Your browser does not support JavaScript
</noscript>
```