# How does Facebook detect if I block javascript on my browser?

Tags: javascript

I had opened my browser setting and blocked Javascript for all websites. But when I tried to access Facebook, it says 
"We're sorry, but Facebook doesn't work properly without JavaScript enabled."
My question is, how they have detected that my browser is not allowing Javascript?

Comment: Why does it matter how *Facebook, in particular,* does this?

Comment: This question is not about programming and therefore doesn't belongs to this site.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to detect if JavaScript is disabled?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/121203/how-to-detect-if-javascript-is-disabled) and [How to inform if Javascript is disabled in the browser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3262479)

Comment: Because they know _everything_ about you...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

They use the [noscript](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/noscript) element to selectively redirect.

```
<noscript><meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0; URL=/?_fb_noscript=1" /></noscript><
```

Answer (score 0):

First – you can display this message by default and remove it with JS.

Seconds – there is a HTML `<noscript>` tag.